# Remove PostgreSQL database files

Tags: linux, database, opensuse, postgresql, sql

I've uninstalled PostgreSQL some time ago, but now I needed it again, and installed it.

When running **rcpostgresql** I get the following:

```
/usr/sbin/rcpostgresql
```

`Your database files were created by PostgreSQL version 9.4.
 Could not find executables for this version.
 Please install the PostgreSQL server package for version 9.4.`

I already removed the files where I created the databases *(using initdb -D)*, but I still can't start it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually pretty simple. I had previously installed PostgreSQL-9.4, but not from the repositories, and I couldn't remember that. Installing the same version helped.

Ok, but **how?** I downloaded the linux binary installer from the website. It has a graphical interface and it's actually pretty easy. This solved the problem.